# ITMS-90238: Invalid Signature when submitting to AppStore with bundled AdoptOpenJDK

Tags: java, signature

When submitting my app to AppStore I get this message from Apple:

***ITMS-90238: Invalid Signature*** - The executable at path MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libfreetype.dylib.6 has following signing error(s): valid on disk /Volumes/data01/app_data/app-processing/mz_16965903542122982835dir/mz_15396195148822940240dir/myPackage.pkg/Payload/MyApp.app/Contents/PlugIns/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libfreetype.dylib.6: satisfies its Designated Requirement test-requirement: code failed to satisfy specified code requirement(s) . Refer to the Code Signing and Application Sandboxing Guide at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/AboutCS/AboutCS.html and Technical Note 2206 at https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2206/_index.html for more information.

The app is submitting just fine with Oracle JDK hence there must be something special with this libfreetype.dylib.6 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are 2 files libfreetype.dylib.6 and libfreetype.6.dylib with identical content within AdoptOpenJDK. I was using a filter for signing *.dylib files and hence the libfreetype.dylib.6 file was not included within the filter and hence not signed. By updating the filter to also include *.dylib.* the problem was solved.

This problem did not appear with Oracle JDK because on Mac OS X it does not distribute the libfreetype library.